# Ошибка при установке kivy через pip3 на виртуалке ОС Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kivy, pip, python-3.8

Устанавливал все зависимости и `cython`.

После команды:

```
sudo pip3 install kivy
```

Вылезает ошибка:

> ```
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```